# Is it ok to use First Name Initial and Full Last Name to refer to someone in a blog article?

Tags: blog

Would it be acceptable or correct to refer to someone (e.g. John Smith) as J. Smith in a blog post that belongs to a company?

For example, 'J. Smith provided us his view, which was that 'Xxxxxxxxxx'.'

Comment: Short answer - no. Unless you have written permission from the individual concerned, you are violating GDPR.

Comment: @Chenmunka GDPR is only for the EU. I may be mistaken, but I think I have seen it this way in the US.